# Network manager is not asking for password for new wifi connections Ubuntu 14

Tags: wireless, network-manager

My Network manager is connecting to existing wifi perfectly, but I am unable to connect to new Wifi connections as Network manager is not asking for password. I select the wifi network that I want to connect and select "settings" but nothing happens. I have no way of entering password for new wifi connection. And Wireless networks symbol is not visible on the top right corner of my screen also. Can anyone provide any solution to this? Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Does the icon reappear if you run the command `sudo service network-manager restart?

Comment: Hello jessenorton , I ran the command you suggested but nothing happend. The icon is still missing.